# Unable to add sender ID to AWS SNS text messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I live in India and I have this requirement where I need to change the default sender Id of text messages sent via AWS SNS to the one that is registered for our organization with TRAI. We are trying to send SMS text messages to customers with Indian mobile numbers. I tried passing TemplateID and EntityId that was issued to us by our provider on the AWS console to manually test things out by unfortunately, whenever I receive text message on my mobile, the sender name still shows a random number assigned by AWS and not the sender id that I configured. I also made sure that the template message approved by TRAI is exactly the same but it did not work either. There are no error logs on AWS either because the message was successfully delivered. Its just that the sender id is not the one that I had configured it to be.
Any help on this topic would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

P.S. We registered our template on JIO which is a Telecom provider here in India.

Comment: In which country are you located? [Sender IDs - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-sender-ids.html) says: "Several major markets (including Canada, China, and the United States) don't support using sender IDs." Also, what is JIO? Please link it in your Question.

Comment: I am located in India and I am trying to send text messages to customers in India as well. I looked into the link that you shared and in order to send a message to mobile numbers in India, you need to have a pre-registered sender id which we already registered using JIO (telecom provider here in India)

Comment: Found this: [Pre-register a Sender ID for India in Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-preregister-template-sender-id/) Did you lodge a request with AWS Support to use the Sender ID?

Comment: We already registered our sender ID with the regulatory authority here in India. But I have not tried to request for a sender ID from AWS. I will try doing that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AWS SNS for this. You have to use AWS Pinpoint if you want to use your specific number. With Pinpoint you can also use short-codes and long-codes and can also configure your messages to be promotional or transactional. You can set your sender id in AWS pinpoint as well. Check the documentation below on how to do that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-awssupport-sender-id.html

It doesn't matter if you have any registration with any telco providers as AWS will use it's own infra to send the messages. So you either have to use 100% AWS solution or 100% telco provider services. You can't mix and match both for SMS sending use-case.

UPDATE:

Well SNS and Pinpoint are 2 different services for 2 different use cases. SNS is only for "notifications" and Pinpoint is like a communication service.

As far as sender-id in SNS is concerned, some countries require it as a hard requirement. You can read more about it in the documentation below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-awssupport-sender-id.html

Comment: I have a question, if the AWS pinpoint has the same features as that of AWS SNS (for our use case), then why does SNS does not work when they do have an option to configure sender ID and Template ID as well ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS SNS *does* support using sender IDs together with template and entity IDs for targeting India. If you follow the instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-senderid-india.html, you'll be able to do this.